# How to show specific html elements by URL parameter? Best practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some doubts about how are best practices on showing html elements by URL. I know the basics:

If you request `URL?param=1&param=2` You are telling the server some filters that are not related to the view itself (html components)

If you request `URL#element` you are telling your browser that you want to show a specific id.

But.. What if I want to show two specific elements? For example... I have

1. -select of categories
2. -select of element filtered by the category
3. -Current categories saved

My problem is I don't know how to specify by URL that I only want to show the two selects. They have different id's and I'd like to maintain that not to merge them in a parent element.

Comment: if this is your url (e.g, www.example.com?param=1&param=2) then you can read url from javascript then strip your parameters then make condition if (param=='1'){$('#selectId').css('diplay','block'); elseif {//show this}else{//}

Comment: its better to show your code for getting right hints or answer :)

Comment: And what if I want to select an option from a selector based on a URL parameter?